# Bouncycastle - Native RSA vs. RSA

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

There are two different ciphers in the Bouncy Castle crypto library that you can pass to `PKCS1Encoding`: `NativeRSAEngine` and `RSAEngine`. Is there a difference between these two variants?

Edit:

As Maarten pointed out in his comment, `NativeRSAEngine` is not part of the Bouncy Castle library itself; it is an addition to the Bouncy Castle lightweight API.

Comment: Thank you Marteen for the answer! You're right! The code where NativeRSAEngine is used was not written by me, im just looking over it and in fact, NativeRSAEngine is not from the bouncycastle library it's from com.squareup.crypto.rsa. Elliott also posted a link to the github entry.

Comment: Toned that down a bit, the question itself is not incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [`NativeRSAEngine`](https://github.com/square/jna-gmp/blob/master/bc-rsa/src/main/java/com/squareup/crypto/rsa/NativeRSAEngine.java) is implemented with a native library, while [`RSAEngine`](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/RSAEngine.html) is written entirely in Java. As for which is faster, there is a comment on that `NativeRSAEngine` Javadoc that says *this is much faster using jna-gmp.*